# Ios dismissviewcontroller

Tags: ios, view, controller

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQAlK.png) In my application I have set off View controllers and initial view controller is splash screen. If anywhere in my application I add

`[self super.dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

or

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

its redirecting it to initial view controller . I want to show the previous view controller after dismising the view controller.
I am using Swreveal view controller also in my application.  I can't comment to my question so I edited the question.

Comment: Are you using navigation controller? and why are you calling `super` `dismissViewControllerAnimated`??

Comment: Can you please be more specific on how your "set of view controllers" is arranged in the storyboard?

Comment: I used [self super.dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; and [self  dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; it didn't worked for both . i am using navigation controller and swreveal view controller and initial view controller is splash screen if I add dismiss code anywhere its taking me to the splash screen view i.e initial view controller

Comment: Now I edited the question and I added image of my storyboard .

Comment: just try  [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Use unwindSegue. It is best suited for in this case.